# Rails Gem That makes or utilizes with some quest

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4.1, leaderboard, game-development

Hi i am currently doing a gamification project and i am wondering if there are any gems for rails that makes quests, and some online leader board? and also handles some point system that would be great and thanks. also i am kind of new in rails so can you please explain a little as i have some trouble sometimes in making out in the syntax of the programs.

and thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Gioco](https://github.com/GiocoApp/gioco) or [Merit](https://github.com/tute/merit) both are great gems to give you a gamification-like engine, you still need to do some work, but it will definitely save you a lot of work!

Comment: Hi! i already saw gioco but what is the main difference of the two my first choice was gioco but still ask if there were other and if you know any tutorials that use them on rails 4.1.6 that would really be great as for now just saw some older videos and i dont know if its good but still thanks!

Comment: I have worked with both and both are great, at the end I sticked with Merit because at that time I found the documentation really good.